# Confused by the many versions of Hahn-Banach Separation Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis

I am studying the Hahn-Banach Separation Theorem. However, there are many versions of the theorem, which is quite confusing. So I want to ask some questions to clarify my confusion.

First, some defintions. The following definitions are adopted from the book [Infinite Dimensional Analysis - A Hitchhiker's Guide](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/3540295860)

> Let $X$ be a real vector space and $A, B \subseteq X$ be two
> non-empty, disjoint sets. A **hyperplane** is a set of the form $\{f = c\}$,
> where $f: X \to \mathbb{R}$ is a non-zero linear functional and
> $c \in \mathbb{R}$. The hyperplane is **closed** if $X$ is topological
> and $f$ is **continuous**.
>
> 1. We say $A, B$ are **weakly separated** by a hyperplane $\{f = c\}$ if $ \sup f(A) \leq c \leq \inf f(B) $.
> 2. We say $A, B$ are **properly separated** by a hyperplane if it separates $A, B$ weakly and does not contain all of $A \cup B$.
> 3. We say $A, B$ are **strictly separated** by a hyperplane $\{f = c\}$ if $ f(a) < c < f(b) $ for all $a \in A, b \in B$.
> 4. We say $A, B$ are **strongly separated** by a hyperplane $\{f = c\}$ if $ \sup f(A) < c < \inf f(B) $.

**Question 1**: Why do we need the extra condition in proper separation? Are there two non-empty, disjoint, convex sets that can be weakly separated but cannot be properly separated?

The first version of Hahn-Banach Separation Theorem is purely algebraic and does not require any topological structure.

> Let $X$ be a real vector space and $A, B \subseteq X$ be two
> non-empty, disjoint, convex sets. If one of $A, B$ has an **internal**
> point, then they can be **properly separated** by a hyperplane.

**Question 2:** Is it true that any internal point $x_0$ of $A$ or $B$ must satisfy $f(x_0) < c$ or $f(x_0) > c$?

The second version is from the [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hahn%E2%80%93Banach_theorem#%22Geometric_Hahn%E2%80%93Banach%22_(the_Hahn%E2%80%93Banach_separation_theorems)).

> Let $X$ be a **locally convex** topological vector space and
> $A, B \subseteq X$ be two non-empty, disjoint, convex sets. If
> $A$ has a **non-empty interior**, then they can be **properly separated**
> by a **closed** hyperplane $\{f = c\}$. Moreover, any $x_0 \in A^\circ$
> must satisfy $f(x_0) < c$.

**Question 3**: The wiki page requires $X$ to be locally convex. However, from what I have read from "Infinite Dimensional Analysis", it seems that $X$ is only required to be a topological vector space. Does this version still hold if $X$ is merely a topological vector space?

> Let $X$ be a topological vector space and $A, B \subseteq X$ be
> two non-empty, disjoint, convex sets. If both $A, B$ are **open**, then
> they can be **strictly separated** by a **closed** hyperplane.

This seems to be a direct corollary of the previous version, **provided that the previous version still holds if $X$ is merely a topological vector space**.

> Let $X$ be a **locally convex** topological vector space and $A, B \subseteq X$
> be two non-empty, disjoint, convex sets. If $A$ is **closed** and $B$ is **compact**,
> then they can be **strongly separated** by a **closed** hyperplane.

**Question 4**: I know that if $B$ is merely closed, then we cannot even separate $A, B$ strictly, let alone strong separation. What if we merely need proper separation or weak separation? Can we separate two closed, non-empty, disjoint, convex sets properly or weakly?

Comment: Q1: Let $f$ be a non-zero functional, and $A$,$B$ disjoint dense subspaces of $\ker f$.

Comment: What happened with one question per post?

Comment: @QuantumSpace I've answered questions like this before (I answered one with as many as seven subparts), but I've seen people having problems with them as well (of course, for being too broad). I often tell myself that it makes more sense to have four heavily linked questions in one post, than having four separate questions with tiny, tiny issues in each post. For example, the comment above answers the first subpart, and even with an explanation it would probably be about six lines. I'll put it this way : please try to attempt this question, and I will take up the broadness issue.